# force macos system to downgrade ruby system

Tags: ruby, macos, version, homebrew

I need to be using Ruby 2.2.2 but my macOS came with 2.6.3.

Commands I have tried both as root and not as root:

- `sudo brew install ruby@2.2.2` and `brew install ruby@2.2.2` results in error
- `sudo gem update --system 2.2.2` and `gem update --system 2.2.2` results in the program aborting itself

rvm is not installed.

How do I get Ruby 2.2.2 installed?

edit:

followed the advice below

```
install RVM with \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
Restart your shell
Install Ruby with rvm install 2.2.2
Verify you are using the correct version of Ruby with ruby -v
```

then I got this error:

```
CL-CJAKOB-XMD6R:~ cjakob$ rvm install 2.2.2
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.15/x86_64/ruby-2.2.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system......
Installing required packages: automake, libtool, coreutils, libyaml, libksba, zlib, openssl..............
==> Upgrading 2 outdated packages:
pkg-config 0.29.2 -> 0.29.2_3
readline 8.0.1 -> 8.0.4
==> Upgrading readline 8.0.1 -> 8.0.4 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/readline-8.0.4.catalina.bot
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/6a/6ae1c8e7c783f32bd22c6085caa4d
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring readline-8.0.4.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
==> Caveats
readline is keg-only, which means it was not symlinked into /usr/local,
because macOS provides BSD libedit.

For compilers to find readline you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/readline/include"

For pkg-config to find readline you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/readline/lib/pkgconfig"

==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/readline/8.0.4: 48 files, 1.5MB
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/readline/8.0.1... (48 files, 1.5MB)
==> Upgrading pkg-config 0.29.2 -> 0.29.2_3 
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles/pkg-config-0.29.2_3.catalin
==> Downloading from https://akamai.bintray.com/80/80f141e695f73bd058fd82e9f539d
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring pkg-config-0.29.2_3.catalina.bottle.tar.gz
  /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2_3: 11 files, 623.7KB
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/pkg-config/0.29.2... (11 files, 623KB)
==> Checking for dependents of upgraded formulae...
==> Upgrading 2 dependents:
ruby-build 20200115 -> 20200401, ruby-build 20200115 -> 20200401
==> Upgrading ruby-build 20200115 -> 20200401 
==> Downloading https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/archive/v20200401.tar.gz
==> Downloading from https://codeload.github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/tar.gz/v202004
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> ./install.sh
==> Caveats
ruby-build installs a non-Homebrew OpenSSL for each Ruby version installed and these are never upgraded.

To link Rubies to Homebrew's OpenSSL 1.1 (which is upgraded) add the following
to your ~/.bash_profile:
  export RUBY_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl-dir=$(brew --prefix openssl@1.1)"

Note: this may interfere with building old versions of Ruby (e.g <2.4) that use
OpenSSL <1.1.
==> Summary
  /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-build/20200401: 495 files, 245.2KB, built in 4 seconds
Removing: /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-build/20200115... (470 files, 234.4KB)
==> Checking for dependents of upgraded formulae...
Error: No such file or directory - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby-build/20200115
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
CL-CJAKOB-XMD6R:~ cjakob$
```

how would I move forward from here?

Comment: Why do you need to be using 2.2.2 (it's important to answer otherwise you might be dealing with XY problems -  please google what an xy problem is if you don't know). You can have multiple versions of ruby on your system: you need a ruby version manager to help you. You can get RVM or you can get rbenv. i would recommend the latter because I don't like dealing with gemsets which are needed in RVM. but rvm is still a viable option for you. So you can use whatever ruby version you require. Now to answer your question: you can try installing RVM.

Comment: _gemsets which are needed in RVM_ I've used RVM professionally and personally for over 7 years and have dealt with gemsets exactly once.

Comment: installed rvm as instructed but it resulted in another error which I have added to my question

Comment: Repeat your `rvm install 2.2.2` command and see if it completes successfully now. If not, run `brew doctor` and `brew upgrade` and then retry again.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do not attempt to modify, downgrade, upgrade, remove, or use the built-in version of Ruby on macOS. Instead, use a Ruby version manager to install the specific version of Ruby you require:

- Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
- Restart your shell
- Install Ruby with `rvm install 2.2.2`
- Verify you are using the correct version of Ruby with `ruby -v`

Then retry your operation.

More information on system Ruby can be found at https://dontusesystemruby.com/.

Comment: oops looks im not out of the woods yet

Comment: I had to add `rvm use 2.2.2 --default` for `ruby -v` to display the correct thing.

Comment: More information about this at [Don't use system Ruby](https://dontusesystemruby.com/).

Comment: Hello, anothermh, it's ran for me, but i needed 2.6.0 version and Working on! Thank you

Comment: @RicardoLuizPereira `rvm install 2.6.0`