# Macbook/M1 CPU: instal hiptest-publisher/executable-hooks failed

Tags: ruby, rubygems, apple-m1

When I run hiptest-publisher on Mac's termainl, I'm getting the following error.

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
```

So I run `gem install executable-hooks -v 1.6.1` and getting the following error. It should related to Apple's new M1 CPU.

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.6.1 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.6.1
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/plugins/executable-hooks_plugin.rb": cannot load such file -- executable-hooks/wrapper (LoadError)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing executable-hooks:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/ext/wrapper_installer
/opt/homebrew/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -I /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.3/lib/ruby/3.1.0 extconf.rb
/Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:101:in `initialize': Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ruby/3.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/bin/rdbg (Errno::EACCES)
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:101:in `open'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:101:in `block in try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:99:in `map'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:99:in `try_to_fix_binstubs'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:76:in `block in execute_no_wrapper'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:73:in `each'
    from /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:73:in `execute_no_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:20:in `<main>'
bundler 2.3.26
debug 1.6.3

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/gems/executable-hooks-1.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.0/extensions/arm64-darwin-21/3.1.0/executable-hooks-1.6.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a shell environment that is confused about where to find Ruby and where to install gems. It's mixing up your Homebrew-installed version of Ruby and your RVM gems.

You should uninstall your Homebrew version of Ruby and ensure that `which ruby` refers to the version of Ruby that exists in your `.rvm` directory instead.

1. `brew uninstall ruby`
2. `rm -rf ~/.rvm` to completely remove RVM, Ruby and gems
3. Follow the steps at https://stackoverflow.com/a/61375910/3784008 to reinstall RVM and Ruby (make sure you specify the version you need instead of 2.2.2)
4. Retry `gem install executable-hooks -v 1.6.1`

Comment: Also get used to using `.ruby-version` to specify the ruby to use for each project - you can set a default with RVM, but RVM's strength (or that of `chruby`, etc.) is the ability to have multiple versions installed but select the one to use as appopriate for the project.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15708916/use-rvmrc-or-ruby-version-file-to-set-a-project-gemset-with-rvm) .